# AJAX not updating partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently having difficulty using Ajax to update a partial view without having to refresh the whole page. I'm using MVC and entity framework to scaffold views.

I'll try and include as much as possible to help explain myself:

I have a div which is going to be used to hold a list view of all my comments

```
<div id="ContainAnnouncementComments"> </div>
```

This div gets populated using the following:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Custom_Scripts/BuildAnnouncement.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Comments/BuildAnnouncementComment',
            data: { AnnouncementId: @Model.AnnouncementId},
            success: function (result) {
                $('#ContainAnnouncementComments').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

Which calls the `BuildAnnouncementComment()` method in my controller:

```
 public ActionResult BuildAnnouncementComment(int? AnnouncementId)
        {
            return PartialView("_AnnouncementComment", db.Comments.ToList().Where(x => x.AnnouncementId == AnnouncementId));
        }
```

I then have a second div container which is used to hold a text box for a user to enter some information which 'should' then update the `ContainAnnouncementComments` using Ajax replace call:

```
<div id="ContainAnnouncementCommentCreate">

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AJAXCreate", "Comments", new { announcementId = Model.AnnouncementId }, new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            UpdateTargetId = "ContainAnnouncementComments"
        }))

        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
```

The Ajax method calls the AJAXCreate method in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult AJAXCreate(int announcementId, [Bind(Include = "CommentId, Message")] Comment comment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                comment.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                comment.AnnouncementId = announcementId; 
                db.Comments.Add(comment);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return PartialView("_AnnouncementComment", db.Comments.ToList()); 
        }
```

From here, when running, I try to create a new comment, but when submitted, instead of the partialView being updated, all that is being displayed is the partialview.

Not sure if I've explained this properly so if i'm missing any information please let me know and i'll update accordingly.

Comment: you are missing **jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js** file, include it in the master layout

Comment: I've included <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script> in my .cshtml details view which was generated with entity scaffolding. I just didn't include it in the question, sorry. I'll update to include all my <scripts>'s now.

Comment: do it like ``<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")'></script>``, as the url might get wrong if views are in nested directories, and plese show your layout file, do you have other dependent js files also loaded as **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** probably has dependencies

Comment: Tried that, getting a compilation error: unexpected character?

Comment: see updated comment, try that way

Comment: Heres my layout file. https://codedump.io/share/ZzQoWYYD12ZB/1/layout-file

and tried updated, same compilation error

Comment: you are missing two bundles down there after bootstrap script bundle, add these two there : ``@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unobtrusive")``

Comment: Added those, which has got rid of the compilation error but still when submitted the form, i'm just getting the partial view displayed

Comment: please include all scripts in layout file, don't add them on other views

Comment: and i have given you all the points which needs to addressed, you should be able to make it work fine now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130640/discussion-between-f-bar-and-ehsan-sajjad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 hours of staring at my code I realised that nothing was actually wrong with the implementation and all that was wrong was I hadn't installed AJAX through the NuGet manager.

Joys.